# Touchpad buttons on a HP Elitebook with Ubuntu-20-04 are not working

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, hp, button

I have installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on my HP Elitebook 850 G7, and in Ubuntu I noticed something strange.
While, the touchpad in general works, the two extra buttons do not.

I found a lot of answers dealing with completely non-functioning touchpad, but in my case it's only the two extra buttons that do not work.

Below is some output of `xinput`. It lists two devices named `SYNA30B4`, which I suspect to be the touchpad and the extra buttons.

```
user@host:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA30B4:00 06CB:CE09 Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA30B4:00 06CB:CE09 Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
user@host:~$ xinput list-props 12
Device 'SYNA30B4:00 06CB:CE09 Mouse':
    Device Enabled (174):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (176): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (312):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (313):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (314):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (315):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (316):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (317): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (318): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (319):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (320):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (321): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (322): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (323):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (324):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (325):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (326): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (327): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (297): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (298):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (299):    0, 0
    Device Node (300):  "/dev/input/event12"
    Device Product ID (301):    1739, 52745
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (328):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (329):   1
user@host:~$ xinput list-props 13
Device 'SYNA30B4:00 06CB:CE09 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (174):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (176): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (330): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (331): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (332):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (333):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (334):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (335):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (336):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (337):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (312):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (313):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (338):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (339):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (314):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (315):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (316):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (340): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (341):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (342):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (319):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (320):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (321): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (322): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (326): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (327): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (297): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (298):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (299):    0, 0
    Device Node (300):  "/dev/input/event13"
    Device Product ID (301):    1739, 52745
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (328):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (329):   1
user@host:~$ xinput list-props 15
Device 'Intel HID 5 button array':
    Device Enabled (174):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (176): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (297): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (298):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (299):    0, 0
    Device Node (300):  "/dev/input/event9"
    Device Product ID (301):    0, 0
user@host:~$
```

Comment: As I look to see what might help you I find without the actual model number of the machine I do not get very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue with a more recent Linux kernel.

---

The issue has [already been resolved](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1908992) in the Linux 5.10 kernel. However, my initial installation featured the [linux-oem-20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/linux-oem-20.04) kernel package. This package is based on the Linux 5.6.* kernel.

I have changed to the [linux-oem-20.04b](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/focal-updates/linux-oem-20.04b) kernel package, which is based on the Linux 5.10 kernel.
After installing the new kernel package, and rebooting, the trackpad buttons work as expected.